# Change adb permissions to rw?

Tags: adb, root-access, lineageos

I have LineageOS on my phone. I'm looking to edit some files in `/system`.

I'm using root permission for adb devices from Developers Options. When I request to move file into `/system`, I get the message `no permissions`.

I tried to change permission with chmod but its not working. Since I don't have root permission for apps I can't change it from file manager either.

Comment: This was discussed thousands of times

Answer (score 0):

`adb root` then `adb remount` should be sufficient. However, you can also get [`addonsu`](https://download.lineageos.org/extras) for LineageOS of your version and device architecture, which enables root permissions for apps in Developer Options.

I understand some users might explicitly avoid opening up root for apps, so pick between the two according to your needs.